# xjc unknown location - xsds to java error using JAXB XJC

Tags: java, ant, jaxb, xjc

I am in process to convert multiple xsds to java using JAXB, I am using Jdeveloper version 10.1.3.4 as my IDE. JAXB 1.0 version, Xerces-J 2.6.2

Following is the sequence of the build targets and their output from the below. I have also tried to use the -nv switch 
 
Even the above didn't work. I am new to JAXB.

Please find the below ant log:

```
[echo] Logging started build_2011-11-12.log
writelog:  duration 0 seconds

generation.jaxb.init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\generated
generation.jaxb.init:  duration 0 seconds

generate.jaxb:
      [xjc] build id of XJC is 1.0.2-b15-fcs
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\create_ship_to.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\custom_ship.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\generic_notes.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\meter_log.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\part_need.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\part_usage.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\place.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\place_type.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\request.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\request_contact.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\request_event.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\request_product.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\request_text.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\ship_to.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\shipment.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\stock.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\time_zone_code.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_generic_notes.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_meterlog.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_part_need.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_part_usage.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_place.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_request.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_request_contact.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_request_event.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_request_product.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_request_text.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_ship_to.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\update_type.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\whos_place.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\wmetrix_install_info.xsd
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\xsd\wmetrix_person.xsd
      [xjc] the last modified time of ths inputs is  1320964837275
      [xjc] the last modified time of the outputs is -9223372036854775808
      [xjc] Compiling file:/C:/Users/XXX/Projects/XXXY/Interface/xsd/create_ship_to.xsd and others
      [xjc] [INFO] Using Xerces from jar:file:/C:/Users/XXX/Installs/JDevStudio10.1.3.4/ant/lib/xercesImpl.jar!/org/apache/xerces/impl/Version.class
      [xjc] unknown location
      [xjc] 
generate.jaxb:  duration 0 seconds

BUILD FAILED

C:\Users\XXXY\Projects\XXX\Interface\build.xml:60: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:373)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:246)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.buildNamespaceSupport(DOMScanner.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.parseWithContext(DOMScanner.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:57)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:65)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestParser.parse(DOMForestParser.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader$XMLSchemaForestParser.parse(GrammarLoader.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:183)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.loadXMLSchema(GrammarLoader.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.load(GrammarLoader.java:130)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.load(GrammarLoader.java:79)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask._doXJC(XJCTask.java:331)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask.doXJC(XJCTask.java:283)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask.execute(XJCTask.java:227)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    ... 10 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.buildNamespaceSupport(DOMScanner.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.parseWithContext(DOMScanner.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:57)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestScanner.scan(DOMForestScanner.java:65)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForestParser.parse(DOMForestParser.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader$XMLSchemaForestParser.parse(GrammarLoader.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:183)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.XSOMParser.parse(XSOMParser.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.loadXMLSchema(GrammarLoader.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.load(GrammarLoader.java:130)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.GrammarLoader.load(GrammarLoader.java:79)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask._doXJC(XJCTask.java:331)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask.doXJC(XJCTask.java:283)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask.execute(XJCTask.java:227)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:246)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:67)
```

Please help:

Comment: JAXB 1.0 is quite old, are you able to use JAXB 2 instead?  It requires at least Java SE 5.  An implementation is included with Java SE 6 and 7 (others such as EclipseLink MOXy and Apache JaxMe are also available).

Comment: Thanks Blaise for your quick reply. Actually the upgrading will take place after some time. Unfortunately, I had to work on minor changes with the existing infrastructure.

Comment: Blaise is the Duke of understatement here. To be candid, you'd have to have a gun to your head to use JAXB 1.0 in 2011. JRE 6 ships with JAXB 2.1 built in, JRE 7 ships with JAXB 2.2. The utilities are much better (e.g. maven plugins) than with JAXB 1.0, the generated code much clearer, and lib dependencies reduced greatly, and you can actually find it online.